# JAVA SPLIT - split without removing whitespaces

Tags: java, split

I'm having a difficulty splitting a string without removing whitespaces but removing all other non-characters. I have this school task to read in with `BufferedReader` and the text consists of lots of characters which even eclipse couldn't show. The elements i read in are in form of element1;element 2; element 3 (Element 4; Element 5 $Element 6 etc.. and one of the delimeters to remove should be ";".

I've tried `.split(//W)` but this removed all the whitespaces and some elements stayed completely empty although it removed characters well.

Right now i've used `.split("[;(),$]")` but this does not work properly since there are still characters which i can't recognize..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to split on the all the characters you don't want, you could include all the characters you do want. e.g.

```
String[] words = s.split("[^ a-zA-Z0-9]+");
```

Note: the `^` means anything but these characters.

BTW: none of the characters are non-characters.

Comment: +1 for simple regex. Anyway it could be good idea to exclude all whitespaces from split to prevent potential splitting of `element\n10`.

Comment: This option, aswell as the one below leaves me empty elements into arrays, which i could fix by creating a method to do that (did that before aswell tho, but in the way of creating my code, i deleted it and thought it's not longer neccessery). Or is there an another way to avoid empty elements?

Comment: @PshemoI would add the whitespace you expect because there is quite a few and developers don't always think about it.

Comment: @charen Added a `+` to skip empty elements.  This won't drop a leading empty element.

Answer (score 0):

If you claim that `\\W` worked fine for you but only problem was that it also split on whitespace then you can use intersection of `\\W` and `\\S` which will remove all whitespaces from `\\W`.

Use `split("[\\W&&\\S]+")`

Also to remove whitespaces surrounding results like `_eleement 3` (where `_` represents whitespace) you can surround regex with `\\s*`. To add support for Unicode in predefined character class just add `(?U)` flag to regex.

Demo:

```
String data = "element1;element 2; element 3 (Element 4; Element 5 $Element 6 ";
for (String s:data.split("(?U)\\s*[\\W&&\\S]+\\s*")){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
element1
element 2
element 3
Element 4
Element 5
Element 6
```

Comment: This seems to work fine, but now it seems like //W took away also non-ascii characters (in which my language uses) so if i read in from text file "ä", "ö", "ü" or "ö" it will split from them aswell. Any idea what to add so it would skip these aswell?

Comment: Hmm, it still splits from so called non-ascii character.

vĆ
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ga kiire"

Comment: `NumberFormatException` regex does't throw `NumberFormatException`, it seems that you are trying to parse `ga kiire` with something like `Integer.parseInt` or something similar. For now I can only guess what is problem with your data/code. To make your question answerable please include example which could be used to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Nono, NumberFormatException is given because it does split from wrong place. Without this one split from the Estonian word "väga kiire" there would be another element in this position which is an integer. 

Right now the problem causing word is " vĆga kiire" i believe.

Comment: I understand that, but without seeing how exactly your data should be split I will not be able to help you. I provided answer which solves your problem as it is written now. As I said earlier, you need to provide example which will let me reproduce your current problem. Post data you are trying to split, expected split result and how it is actually being split so I could see what could cause this behaviour.

Comment: Okay, i'll added my code to pastebin, because answering my question wasn't the right thing to do right now and i do not know exactly how the comment section works with code. Commented the code in pastebin..

http://pastebin.com/BdpNR3cH

Comment: @charen It seems that problem is that you don't want to treat `;;` as single separation token, but as two tokens which should produce from `foo;;bar` array of `["foo", "", "bar"]`. If that is the case try changing split to `split("(?U)(;|\\s*[\\W&&\\S]+)\\s*")`. Also you will have to remove first empty element from result array so either start iterating from `1` or just use `tükid = Arrays.copyOfRange(tükid, 1, tükid.length)` instead of your `clean` method.